# Returning a nested observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Given this method:

```
public logIn(data:any): Observable<any> {
  this.http.get('https://api.myapp.com/csrf-cookie').subscribe(() => {
    return this.http.post('https://api.myapp.com/login', data);
  });
}
```

I would like it to return that nested observable, so that my calling code can use it like so:

```
this.apiService.logIn(credentials).subscribe(() => {
    // redirect user to their dashboard
});
```

without needing to know about the first `/csrf-cookie` request. Obviously the above doesn't work - but I'm struggling to understand how to make the inner HTTP request wait for the outer one to finish AND be returned by the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `switchMap` see the [documentation on switch map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap)

```js
public logIn(data:any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('https://api.myapp.com/csrf-cookie').pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.http.post('https://api.myapp.com/login', data))
  );
}
```

with rxjs nested subscribes are generally not a good idea. There are many great operators within the library that will get you around it. In this case above where one call depends on another `switchMap(...)` is the best fit.

Also the code has been modified to return the `observable` not the `subscription`